# Simplifying Django views form handling logic

Tags: python, django

Just a shot in the dark, but maybe someone is able to suggest something interesting.

Whenever I have **forms** in my view, there are a lot of *if-else* statements, and it is hard to follow the logic. Is there some pattern or python language feature to simplify this? I've had this problem for as long as I can remember, and found no good solution to this day.

Here is an example: view that renders the same page if there are errors, and if all is good does the search (on a model) and returns a page with the graphs:

```
def analysis(request):
    context = {'main_navigation' : 'analysis'}
    context['no_results'] = False
    template = 'analysis/analysis.html'

    # Search params?
    if not request.GET:
        form = AnalysisSearchForm()
        context['form'] = form
    else:
        form = AnalysisSearchForm(request.GET)
        context['form'] = form
        if form.is_valid():            
            # Do the search
            results = form.search()

            if len(results) > 0:                
                context['results'] = json.dumps(results, default=encode)
                context.update(form.cleaned_data)

                # Add the compare form
                context['compare_form'] = CompareForm();

                # Add critical level if there is one.
                part = form.cleaned_data.get('part', None)
                if part:
                    level = Level.get(part, "Default")
                    if level is not None:
                        context['level'] = level.value

                template = 'analysis/analysis_graphs.html'
            else:                                
                context['no_results'] = True

    return render_to_response(template, context,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

As you can see the above is already simplified by moving all the querying logic into *form.search()* method, which uses the form's cleaned_data to (in this case) contact the remote API and fetch the results.

Comment: You could take the contents of one of your if statements and factor it out as a separate function.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at Class Based Views (new in 1.3). You write your views as classes and inherit the necessary funcionality from multiple base views and also mixins. This means you can break your views out into their constituant parts and have nice code separation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/

Furthermore there are mixins made particularly for dealing with forms:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#formmixin

They take a bit of reading to make the most of them, but I really like the implementation and it looks like it is a good approach to overcoming some of the problems you mentioned.

Comment: Wuow, that looks interesting! Reading the class-based views page now. Do you use form mixins? What is an example use case for them?

Comment: I'm using class based views but I haven't had to do up a form yet. An example use case is any time you are processing a form in your view!

Comment: Hm... I am having hard time understanding how it applies to me. It seems mixins do a lot of redirecting - whereas in my case it is all in the GET method, and many if statements...

Answer (score 0):

Here how i will do (with small changes and hopping i didn't break the function logic):

```
# XXX: Use Dependency injection with the template file.
def analysis(request, template='analysis/analysis.html'): 
    context = {'main_navigation' : 'analysis'}
    context['no_results'] = False

    # XXX: Create only one form here without the need for if else.
    form = AnalysisSearchForm(request.GET or {})
    context['form'] = form

    if form.is_valid():            
        # The rest of your code here ... .
```

Comment: Yes, interesting... but would form be valid if it is empty? And would that no show an error on intial page load?

Comment: @drozzy: AFAIK an empty form is always invalid you can check it in you python cli: `from django.forms import From; print Form().is_valid()` i will return False.

Comment: But there is a difference in returning "invalid form" vs. "initial empty form" - in the latter case there should be no errors on the page.